# Ambiguous compiling of string array with non-constant size?

Tags: c++, arrays, scope

My gcc compiler from mingw64 8.1.0 doesn't allow the following to be compiled because *var* has to be a constant value:

```
    int var=3;
    string str[var];

int main(){
```

However, doing the same within main() doesn't show any errors:

```
int main(){
    int var;
    cin >> var;
    string str[var];
```

Why is there an ambiguity?

My compile command is simple: `g++ main.cpp`

These are the headers I had included in the beginning for both the cases:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
```

Comment: variable length arrays aren't a part of C++ at all. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: GCC supports variable length arrays as extension, but they can only be allocated on stack, not in the global memory area.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen This could be the answer to this question. P.S. My compile command is simple "g++ main.cpp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your compile flags, they're *both* "wrong":

**Code:**

```
#include <string>

int i = 3;
std::string s1[i];

int main ()
{
  int j = 3;
  std::string s2[j];
  return 0;
}
```

**g++ -o tmp3 -g -pedantic -Wall tmp3.cpp**

```
tmp3.cpp:4:17: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token
 std::string s1[i];
                 ^
tmp3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
tmp3.cpp:9:19: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘s2’ [-Wvla]
   std::string s2[j];
```

Remembering that VLAs are a 'C' feature ("discouraged" in C++, only supported as an "extension"), here are the rules:

> https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array
>
> Declarator for VLA of unspecified size (can appear in function
> prototype scope only) where expression
>
> - any expression other than
>   comma operator, designates the number of elements in the array
>   qualifiers
> - any combination of const, restrict, or volatile
>   qualifiers, only allowed in function parameter lists; this qualifies
>   the pointer type to which this array parameter is transformed

Importantly:

> Objects of any variably-modified type may only be declared at block
> scope or function prototype scope.

This is precisely why the first example is an "error"; the second a "warning".  VLAs *must* be stack-allocated variables.

Comment: This answers my question. Thanks. To put the answer simply: this isn't allowed in global scope, while it is permitted with warnings within a function/main scope.

Comment: VLAs are not "discouraged" in C++.   They are not part of the C++ standard at all.   Since an array dimension is required in the C++ standard to be a compile-time constant, the use of VLAs is actually a diagnosable error in C++.

Comment: @FoggyDay I don't understand this part: ".... VLAs must be stack-allocated variables." How can a variable length array be stack allocated? It doesn't know exactly how much space to pre-allocate for the container. While declaring this VLA, I didn't use pointers. So, is it getting stored in the heap or in stack?

Comment: @Vaisak Mohan: if a variable is local, and you didn't create it with the "new" operator (heap allocation), then it's allocated from the stack.  Here's a good, high-level summary: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-vs-heap-memory-allocation/

Answer (score 0):

> However, doing the same within main() doesn't show any errors

It would tell that this code is not correct C++ if you call it properly:

```
g++ -Wpedantic t.cpp
```

produces this warning:

```
t.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
t.cpp:3:16: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘arr’ [-Wvla]
     int arr[var];
```

for this t.cpp file:

```
int main(){
    int var = 3;
    int arr[var];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GCC accepts Variable Length Arrays (VLAs) as a language extension, but only in certain situations (emphasis mine):

> These arrays are declared like any other automatic arrays, but with a length that is not a constant expression. The storage is allocated at the point of declaration and deallocated when the **block scope** containing the declaration exits

> As an extension, GCC accepts variable-length arrays as a **member of a structure or a union**.

> You can also use variable-length arrays as **arguments to functions**:

Creating an array outside of block scope (i.e. in global memory area) is not one of the accepted use-cases for VLA. See the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html#Variable-Length).

Note that, as everyone else mentioned, VLAs are GCC extension and are not a part of C++ standard. MSVC for example will not compile them at all.